# IronPython Function Calling from String

Tags: python, string, function, expression, ironpython

Bear with me as I'm new to Python.

Basically, I'm trying to set a boolean within a definition like so:

```
Params.HideScopeBoxes = True
```

This is based on:
http://revitapisearch.com/html/35cd76fc-ba75-7d6d-ca28-16b13f618f31.htm

The problem is I want to be able to swap out HideScopeBoxes based on a parameter for the function.

I can do this with a string however, whenever I try to set it to True or False I get "can't assign to call function error". I assume this is because it is trying to do False = True. When I write it out as above though, it works fine.

Here is the code:

[image: PICTURE of code]

Comment: My question is whether I can make "HideScopeBoxes" a variable so that I could call differen't properties using the same function.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

used setattr(object, name, value)